# I am getting a list index out of range although i am accessing the first element of a csv

Tags: python

I am getting a list index out of range for accessing the first element of a csv

I am using this code to search for a competitor's data by comparing their ID to one in the csv:

```
def search_competitor_button():
    asearchid=searchid.get()
    found = 0
    with open ('competitordetails.txt','rU') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            compidfound = row[0]
            if(asearchid == compidfound):
                found = 1
    if(found == 0):
        msg.showerror("Error", "Competitor ID is not valid")
        searchid.set("")
    else:
        compforenamesearch =  row[1]
        compsurnamesearch = row[2]
        compagsearch = row[3]
        comppostcodesearch = row[4]
        compphonenumbersearch = row[5]
        if(row[6] == 1):
            compgendersearch = "Male"
        else:
            compgendersearch = "Female"
```

the csv has 7 elements but i am getting this error for a reason that
i don't know.

Traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\brent\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\Program\WonderWalls Program.py", line 94, in search_competitor_button
    compidfound = row[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Data in file:

```
233,David,Davidson,15,BT667YH,07382647292,1
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with your traceback? (Also note that if this is a homework problem, you may find that the community is less likely to just give you an answer)

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\brent\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\Program\WonderWalls Program.py", line 94, in search_competitor_button
    compidfound = row[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If you could, please add that to your post - that makes it more likely that people will read through and see where your error comes from.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, ill do it now

Comment: Did you try `print(row)` before you try to access `row[0]` to debug? I suspect there's an empty line at the end of your csv, which the `csv.reader` would read as an empty list.

Comment: I have done this and it printed everything correctly, but it seems to cause the error when puts row[0] in the variable compidfound

Comment: You're saying you can run `print(row[0])`, but not `var = row[0]`? I am dubious.

Comment: You were right, there must have been an empty line in the file. Thanks for your help, now i just need to sort out the rest of it, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your `reader` object will interpret an empty line as a list with no entries. You can get around this by either removing the empty line, or adding custom logic to handle rows of length 0.

e.g.

```
for row in reader:
    if len(row) == 0:
        continue
    compidfound = row[0]
    if(asearchid == compidfound):
        found = 1
```